# How to make a collapsing toolbar in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

so im trying to implement a simple collapsing toolbar, but I don't think my xml layout is correct. The text is appearing the image and when I scroll down, I can't scroll back up to see the image. Hope you guys can help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardInfo_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/cardInfo_collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/image_kyoto"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello there"
                android:textSize="30dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello there"
                android:textSize="30dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello there"
                android:textSize="30dp"/>        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello there"
            android:textSize="30dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here's the image
[image]

Comment: You are using the CollapsingToolbarLayout widget, but you do not have a Toolbar element in your xml. Is that on purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ImageView should have  attribute called

```
app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
```

If you want to add Toolbar to your Layout there should be attribute called

```
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
```

And finally You missed one attribute for NestedScrollView.

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Answer (score 3):

in your ImageView, add the following attribute:

```
app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
```

Also, in your NestedScrollView tag, add the following:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Comment: That made it collapse, but the "Hello there texts are still over the image not underneath?!?

Comment: ok, try giving your AppBarLayout tag a definite height:


android:layout_height="250dp"

Comment: yeah that did the trick. Don't know why i can't use wrap_content?

Comment: I believe you can, but be sure to add:

android:fitSystemWindows="true" to all your views within and including the AppBarLayout.

It was confusing to me at first, I found this to help clarify any issue:
https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.mkps05g3s