# Animation effect for User Profile view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-scrollview, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to animate my View like the **Profile Section of the Happn android app**.

After using `coordinatorlayout` as well as `Scrollview`,
I failed to get the same effect as used in Happn Android App.

Can someone help me with that effect?

[image: I need the same profile scrolling animation/effect]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881879/how-to-make-a-collapsing-toolbar-in-android and https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=kA7&channel=fs&ei=bQaZW8K6L8XfvgT4s5bACQ&q=collapsing+toolbar+layout+ina+ndorid+stackoverflow&oq=collapsing+toolbar+layout+ina+ndorid+stackoverflow&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1j33i10k1.5044.7287.0.7434.14.13.0.0.0.0.317.2060.0j4j3j2.9.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..5.9.2054...33i10i160k1j33i13i10i21k1j33i13i21k1.0.o8gC5hMUlc0

Comment: Done that. I am not getting the same effect as in the gif I have attached.

Comment: Would you add the codes you already tried and didn't gave the expected effect? In my view, it's a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with perhaps some additional effects which if you could paste your codes, We'd be able to help you more with that.