# Toolbar not collapsing in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this simple layout:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/primaryDarkColor">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I scroll the `MaterialToolbar` isn't hiding, before I had a `CoordinatorLayout` and it was working. I can't find how to fix it back so when I scroll the `MaterialToolbar` is hidden. Here is a photo of how it looks : https://i.stack.imgur.com/v93av.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a collapsing toolbar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881879/how-to-make-a-collapsing-toolbar-in-android)

Comment: I've seen this post but I'm not using `CollapsingToolbarLayout `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a solution here : https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/android-appbarlayout-with-bottomnavigationview-hide-toolbar-on-scroll-with-fixed-bottomnavigationview/

Also if some people wants it to be with `LinearLayout` I've made it this way:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/primaryDarkColor">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

     <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing LinearLayout with CoordinatorLayout. The attribute app:layout_behavior only works for children inside CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: When I replace to `CoordinatorLayout` the toolbar is collapsing but the end of my recyclerview is hidden. i.e. the link: https://imgur.com/a/6a4RITd

Comment: Try adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your recyclerview. This usually works for the top app bar, I don't know about a bottom one

Comment: @Biscuit One simple way is to add bottom padding to the recyclerview. The padding should be equal to height of the bottom navigation view which is 56dp.

Comment: I'd rather not do that, as this application is for a large variety of phone and tablet

Comment: Then why don't you take bottom bar outside of CoordinatorLayout and maybe put the CoordinatorLayout and BottomNavigationView inside a ConstraintLayout. And then setup UI in such a way that CoordinatorLayout is always on top of BottomNavigationView? That way the toolbar scrolls and you would not have to add any padding at all to recyclerview.